# Creating serverless opensearch collection, "member must satisfy constraint"

Tags: amazon-web-services, opensearch

### Partially resolved but not solved

After taking the dog for a walk and returning after 15 minutes, I tried yet again to create the index. With the exact same parameters as below. I don't know what's more frustrating; it working, or that nothing changed.

The dashboard still doesn't work.

---

I'm losing the will to make this work. I've recreated the collection about 4 times now assuming there must be *something* I'm doing wrong when following this tutorial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/gsg-serverless.html#gsg-encryption.

**TLDR; this is the error I get when trying to Create vector index**:

```
1 validation error detected: Value '[collection/products]' at 'resource' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy constraint: [Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: index/[a-z][a-z0-9-]{3,32}/(?![_-])[a-z0-9][a-z0-9_-]*(?<![,:"*+/\|?#<>])]
```

So there's a missing `index` somewhere, but where? Looks like it must be related to the user?

### IAM Policy

Here's the very permissive IAM policy (yes, I know the * means I can remove all the other policies, but it was just a desperate attempt at making this work) I've connected to my user;

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "aoss:BatchGetCollection",
                "aoss:DeleteCollection",
                "aoss:UpdateAccessPolicy",
                "aoss:CreateAccessPolicy",
                "aoss:CreateSecurityPolicy",
                "aoss:ListCollections",
                "aoss:ListAccessPolicies",
                "aoss:CreateCollection",
                "aoss:DashboardsAccessAll",
                "aoss:APIAccessAll",
                "aoss:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "76.76.21.0/24",
                        "85.224.0.0/13"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Don't worry about the IPs for now – I know.

### Data access policy (probably the issue?)

Because I assumed this is where the error was, this is the only place I deviated from the tutorial and added collection resource to the rules. Note! That I can't add a * after `collection/products` due to an error.

```json
[
  {
    "Rules": [
      {
        "Resource": [
          "collection/products"
        ],
        "Permission": [
          "aoss:CreateCollectionItems",
          "aoss:DeleteCollectionItems",
          "aoss:UpdateCollectionItems",
          "aoss:DescribeCollectionItems"
        ],
        "ResourceType": "collection"
      },
      {
        "Resource": [
          "index/products/*"
        ],
        "Permission": [
          "aoss:CreateIndex",
          "aoss:DeleteIndex",
          "aoss:UpdateIndex",
          "aoss:DescribeIndex",
          "aoss:ReadDocument",
          "aoss:WriteDocument"
        ],
        "ResourceType": "index"
      }
    ],
    "Principal": [
      "BLA"
    ],
    "Description": "products"
  }
]
```

---

### EDIT 1

This smells funny to me when I try to create a new collection (again);

```
The default principal is invalid please choose standard create option to configure this manually.
```

Meaning that there is something wrong with my user? It's not malformed, I chose it in the visual search thing. But how can the IAM policy be wrong when it's so permissive...

### EDIT 2:

Duuh, I probably have to create the index first THEN I can create the vector embeddings... I think...

**But; the OpenSearch Dashboard URL is showing up as Not supported, even thou I followed the tutorial to a T.**

### EDIT 3:

No I couldn't create the index programmatically either, there's definitely/maybe something wrong with my IAM policy. Also, I've now recreated this thing 6 times and the OpenSeach Dashboard URL is always Not Supported.

Comment: Looking at the tutorial I can see that the data access policy includes `"Resource":["index/books/*"],` a statement matching nicely the pattern included in your error message. You sure you should not use `"Resource":["index/products/*"]` in your case.

Comment: You can see the "Resource": ["index/products/*"] for the index resource type, so it's there still just that it's alongside another collection resourcetype. I have tried with and without the collection resource type as an additional rule.

Comment: Ho yeah there are two. Well clearly the error indicates that the first one is wrong. Remove it and update the error message you get then.

Comment: Same error message. And no, that's not what it clearly indicates (wrong) – that's the data policy the visual editor returns when creating a data policy while creating the collection. 
But the latest one I created I didn't add that, and the first, and the third.

I've just tried creating access tokens too thinking maybe the dashboard would at least become available as per a comment in the tutorial. Nope.

Comment: Did you get `1 validation error detected: Value '[collection/products]' ...` after you removed any reference to `collection/products`? I'm puzzled.

Comment: Yes. Like I said in my post, and then in my comments, the only thing I changed from the tutorial was the Data Policy after it started showing this same error.

So yes, that is the same error I'm receiving.

Further clarification – this `1 validation error detected: Value '[collection/products]' ...` is the error I'm receiving with the Data Policy from the tutorial AND from the visual editor provided by aws.

Comment: Ok I tried your data access policy with a valid principal and it worked like a breeze, my user has admin privilege so I didn't bother with step1, I created the resource in us-east-1. As a side note I didn't have to create the collections before the data access policy. I would check step 1 and your privileges.